# Why can't k3s access host services that listening loopback address?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I deployed k3s on a single Ubuntu machine.

Other services are installed on this machine directly (outside k8s), e.g. Redis, Mysql... They are listening loopback address `127.0.0.1` for the security reason.

But the service inside k3s cannot connect to my db. If I change the listening address to `0.0.0.0`, the problem will be fixed.

Why? And what is the best practice in this use case?

PS: I use `Endpoints` to map host service to k8s:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 6379
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: redis
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: xxxxx (host's ip)
    ports:
      - port: 6379
```

[image: structure]

Comment: if you configured the applications to only listening on `lo` in the container there is no way to make their port accessible out of the container.

Comment: @BaptisteMille-Mathias Let me clarify. My db services were installed outside the k8s or any containers, directly on the host.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you Redis just listening on the 127.0.0.1 of your host, and you `svc` try to redirect request to 200.0.0.0? that will not work. that's why 0.0.0.0 could work. your Redis should listening on 200.0.0.0

Comment: @vincentpli You are right. I thought that since K8s is on the same host as redis, then `lo` should be able to access. Looks like I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @vincent pli, I realized that I confused `lo` with host itself.

A service listens to `lo`, does not mean that all services actually running on this machine can access it. If that's what you really want, you must make sure that these two services are in the same virtual network card (`lo`).

Otherwise, if you want to access through an ip address, the service must listen it. If this address is only inside the LAN, it's still safe. Or use the firewall to enforce more stringent inbounds restrictions.